# How do i print the value that a pointer in class point to

Tags: c++, pointers, void-pointers

**hi guys!**

i have a question please:-

if i have a void pointer "vp" and this pointer is a member of class "cl" how can i print the value that pointer "vp" point to? thanks in advance
this is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<conio.h>



using namespace std;

class putIN
{
  public:
     void *vp;
     int *intP;float *floatP;double *doubleP;
     int valueInt;
     double valueDouble;
     char valueFloat;

     putIN();
     putIN(int x);
     putIN(double x);
     putIN(float x);
     ~putIN()
        { 
          delete intP;
          delete floatP;
          delete doubleP;
        }
 };


putIN::putIN(int x){vp = & valueInt; *((int*)vp) = x;}
putIN::putIN(float x){vp = & valueFloat; *((float*)vp) = x;}
putIN::putIN(double x){vp = & valueDouble; *((double*)vp) = x;}


int main()
{
  putIN x = 5;
  cout<<?????<<endl;// what do i have to put instead of the ??????
                    //to print the value that *vp point to
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print the value OF the pointer (i.e. the address), just use `putIN.vb`.

If you want to print the value the pointer POINTS TO, then you have to know wich type (use for example casts, like you did in the constructor.  But do you store an info about the type somewhere, so that you can remember later what you did store ?

By the way, your `delete`statements will segfault, because you try to delete a pointer that was not obtained via `new`.

I didn't fully understand what you try to achieve, but you could elaborate a little bit, with something like this:

```
class putIN
{
  public:
     char mytype;   // I for int, F for float, etc... 
     void *vp;
     union {        // as you use only one of them:
         int valueInt;
         double valueDouble;
         float valueFloat;
         } value; 
     ...
 };
 putIN::putIN(int x){vp = &value.valueInt; *((int*)vp) = x; mytype='I'; }
```

With this in mind, you could then overload operator<<

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, putIN p) {
   if (mytype=='I') 
       os << *(int*)vp;
   else // ... the handling of other supported types here
   return os;
}
```

You would then just output the result in `main()`by writing `cout<<x<<endl;`

The other alternative would be to create a template class.

```
    template <class T>
    class putIN
    {
      public:
         T *vp;
         T value;

         putIN(T x) {vp = &value; *vp = x;}
         ~putIN() {}
     //...
     };
```

And still another approach would be to use [`boost:variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/variant.html) which provides all your need, ready to use and already tested.

Comment: thanks for helping
i want to print the value that the pointer point to
i didn't stored an info about the type in anywhere and i have no idea about how to do that
can you please give me any tutorial link

Comment: @AlexanderHB: If you want to print the value of the object it points to, you might want to update your question's title. It currently asks about printing the value of the pointer itself.

Comment: @Christophe:tyvm i'll try your code
i'm trying to make a class that can allocate a memory for all data types
for example putIN x = 5 will allocate memory for integer
                     putIN y = 0.5 will allocate memory for float
                     putIN z = 'a' will allocate memory for char
                    and so on